# Blender Python get grease pencil stroke points' thickness or pressure value

Tags: python, blender, bpy

my question is the title itself

How do you get the grease pencil strokes' thickness per point?

Cycle thru every points in the gp stroke and determine if they are a certain thickness?

Is it possible? Thank you in advance!

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! You seem to be asking for someone to write some code for you. Stack Overflow is a question and answer site, not a code-writing service. Please see [Ask] to learn how to write effective questions.

Comment: No I'm not asking for code, I'm asking for the proper syntax